# Удалить дубликаты в Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть таблица, в которой имеются 4 колонки, необходимо по "Номеру анкеты" найти дублирующие анкеты и удалить их, оставив только одну анкету. Дело в том, что удаляя функцией drop_duplicates, он оставляет лишь первые вопросы анкет, при этом все остальные вопросы он удаляет. Мне же необходимо, чтобы оставались все вопросы на месте, а все остальные анкеты с таким же "Номером анкеты" были удалены.
Пример входных данных:

```
Номер анкеты   Вопрос                   Ответ                      Узлы
```

---

```
2fcc8   Ваш пол?                   Жен.                    Нет патологий
2fcc8   Ваш возраст?               с 40 до 55              Нет патологий
2fcc8   Вы курите?                 Да                      Нет патологий
2fcc8   Сколько лет вы курите?     от 15 до 30 лет         Нет патологий
bdab0   Ваш пол?                   Жен.                    Нет патологий
bdab0   Ваш возраст?               с 40 до 55              Нет патологий
bdab0   Вы курите?                 Да                      Нет патологий
bdab0   Сколько лет вы курите?     от 15 до 30 лет         Нет патологий 
2fcc8   Ваш пол?                   Жен.                    Нет патологий
2fcc8   Ваш возраст?               с 40 до 55              Нет патологий
2fcc8   Вы курите?                 Да                      Нет патологий
2fcc8   Сколько лет вы курите?     от 15 до 30 лет         Нет патологий
```

И то каким я вижу выходной файл:

```
Номер анкеты   Вопрос                   Ответ                      Узлы
```

---

```
2fcc8   Ваш пол?                   Жен.                    Нет патологий
2fcc8   Ваш возраст?               с 40 до 55              Нет патологий
2fcc8   Вы курите?                 Да                      Нет патологий
2fcc8   Сколько лет вы курите?     от 15 до 30 лет         Нет патологий
bdab0   Ваш пол?                   Жен.                    Нет патологий
bdab0   Ваш возраст?               с 40 до 55              Нет патологий
bdab0   Вы курите?                 Да                      Нет патологий
bdab0   Сколько лет вы курите?     от 15 до 30 лет         Нет патологий
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: можно пример кода?

Comment: Лучше не пример кода, а пример исходных данных и пример желаемого результата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то попробуйте вот так:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Номер анкеты', 'Вопрос'], keep='first')
```

Comment: Он почему то в некоторых случаях, полностью удаляет дубликаты, оставляя лишь одну анкеты с вопросами. А в некоторых моментах оставляет один дублирующий вопрос из анкеты.

Comment: Значит у вас вопросы разные. Не в плане семантики - а в плане символов. Проверьте пробелы, запятые, точки, служебные (невидимые) симоволы и пр.  Чудес в программировании не бывает.